# Viewport Display Material colour and Principled BSDF base colour

Tags: 3d-view

Most likely an easy answer,

How do I get viewport display material colour and principled BSDF base colour to be the same colour if switch shading overviews (always the same colour).

It's a little jarring to see no colour, the wrong colours on an item when I switch viewport shading style.

ps. as in an automatic way. not pick a colour, copy hex code and past into other colour box.

Answer (score 3):

Just three steps really :)

1. Switch viewport shading color to *Object*
2. Add *Object Info > Color* node into your material
3. Control color through *Properties > Object > Color*

[image]